# Exporting model with tensorflow transform without Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-transform

All of the examples I have seen with tensorflow transform export the models after training using an estimator with the export_saved_model function.  I am working with existing training code that does not use estimators and saves with saved_model.simple_save.

What is the best practice method for saving a transform_fn with a model for serving without using estimators?

Comment: Convert the model to estimator and export it as tfx is mainly built on tensorflow estimators